# Where does Firebase store config values set using the CLI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Using

```
firebase functions:config:set MY_KEY="..."
```

I was able to find a way to share sensitive information to my functions.
At first I thought this function was just setting local values used for during the deployment, but then If I use `firebase functions:config get` on another local machine I am able to retrieve the values, which means they are uploaded in the cloud.

I like to know where things are and knowing there are ways to monitor values remotely but I was unable to find where Firebase stores these values in the console.

Is there a way to browse these values from the console? and if yes where should I go?

Comment: You can see for yourself in the [CLI source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks a lot, I'll try to find answers there! However I'm not going to lie but this code source is pretty huge, if you could give me a hint where to search. If not, that's ok:) I'll eventually find what I'm looking for, just trying to get an answer from experienced people.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok so maybe that's it `/v1beta1/projects/${projectId}/adminSdkConfig` ? It's actually an API call.
My question was more about "is there a UI interface in Firebase or GC where I can easily monitor that information?" *visually*, not using the firebase CLI or directly calling an API endpoint....